# How to modify System workflow message with a modern look Header?

Tags: css, system-workflow-messages, html

I would like to add some fancy CSS and HTML in the system workflow messages. I know there’s a section to add a header logo. But I was wondering if there’s an ideal way  to make the entire format responsive like modern emails. I have tried copying and pasting some CSS HTML from mail chimp although it works but In th drupal log there’s 100s error (User error: smarty......) gets registered per email is sent.

If someone has done already something like this I would be very grateful if you share your sample code please. Or even some suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your css inside {literal}{/literal} tags to prevent smarty from processing them.

Comment: thanks !!! that worked.

Comment: Great I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your css inside {literal}{/literal} tags to prevent smarty from processing them.